# A specific description of a function $f(x)$. Does $f(x)$ have to be continuous at $x=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $I$ be the subset $[-1,1]$ of $\Bbb R$. Consider a function $f:I\to I$ with properties:

(a) $f(x) = 0$  at all points $x_n = 2^{1-n}$ and $y_n = -2^{1-n}$ in $I$ ($n$ varies throughout all natural numbers).

(b) $f(x)$ is continuous at all these points.

(c) $f(x)$ is a bounded function.

(d) For all integers $n$, $f(x)$ with domain restricted to $[-2^{-n},2^{-n}]$ is equal to $\dfrac 1 {a^n}f(2^nx)$ for some fixed constant  $a > 1$.

(e) $f(0) = 0.$

Is $f(x)$ necessarily continuous at the point $x = 0$?

Comment: Do you mean $n$ varies throughout all *natural* numbers perhaps?

Comment: yes, thanks for correction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By hypothesis (d), $f(0)=a^{-1}f(0)$ hence $f(0)=0$. By hypothesis (c), there exists a finite $c$ such that $|f(x)|\leqslant c$ for every $|x|\leqslant1$. By hypothesis (d) again, $|f(x)|\leqslant ca^{-n}$ for every $|x|\leqslant2^{-n}$, for every $n\geqslant0$. Thus $f(x)\to0$ when $x\to0$ and $f$ is continuous at $0$.

(Hypotheses (a), (b) and (e) are not needed.)

Comment: Clearly you are correct. I was trying to make up a question which was trickier and which encorporated (a), (b) and (e) and trying to see when f is continuous at x = 0. My question above is too easy because of (c) and (d).

Comment: Got rid of hypothesis (e) as well.

Comment: hahahaha that seriously made me laugh. I meant to write (d) with each of those intervals not containing 0.